# How to add a button to static UITableView using storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I tried to add UIButton in UITableView below UITableViewCells using storyboard.

However, the button width filled the whole area. I could net reduce the width of UIButton using storyboard. Do I have to add it programmatically?

I'm trying to active a result similar like the button in Viber setup, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Please add screenshots of your work-in-progress. I've done this several times and never encountered any problems, but maybe you're new and thus missing something not-so-obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `UIButton` directly at the end of your table view, you're making it the table view footer, and the table view footer is required to take the whole table view width.

Try replacing your `UIButton` with a `UIView`, and add the `UIButton` in this `UIView`:

[image: View hierarchy]

[image: Storyboard appearance]